# None type returned / Tag not found

Tags: xpath, lxml, xml.etree

I have to parse a file to find min and mult qty of each `sku`

```
<product sku="13603">
  <sku>13603</sku>
  <quantity unit="pcs">
    <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
    <step-quantity>1</step-quantity>
  </quantity>    
</product>
<product sku="13713">
  <sku>13713</sku>
  <quantity unit="pcs">
    <min-order-quantity>1</min-order-quantity>
    <step-quantity>1</step-quantity>
  </quantity>
</product>    
...
```

My program is very simple

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('./file-above.xml')
for elem in tree.iterfind('product'):
vSKU = elem.find('sku').text
vMin = elem.find('quantity/min_order_quantity').text
```

When I run it, it creates an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

When run interactively and changing the last line to...

```
print elem.find('sku').text
```

it works, but the line...

```
print elem.find('quantity/min_order_quantity').text
```

fails. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your XPath, you need `vMin = elem.find('quantity/min-order-quantity').text` instead of `vMin = elem.find('quantity/min_order_quantity').text` (i.e. hyphen instead of underscore)